# What is the homeomorphism from $\Gamma \backslash T_1 \mathbb{H}$ to $T_1(\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, hyperbolic-geometry, surfaces, fuchsian-groups

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be hyperbolic plane, $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R}$) so that $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ is a compact hyperbolic surface. Maybe it will be very simple to you but I am very confused when I try to construct a homeomorphism $\phi: \Gamma \backslash T_1 \mathbb{H} \longrightarrow T_1(\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H})$

Suppose $\Gamma (z,v)$ is an element of $\Gamma \backslash T_1 \mathbb{H}$, so what is $\phi (\Gamma (z,v))$? Actually I read in some book and they always accept this fact obviously, but for me it's not obvious.

I'm so sorry if it is not a question of researching.

Comment: $T_1 \mathbb{H}$ is unit tangent bundle of hyperbolic plane. An element of $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a orientation-preserving isometry of $\mathbb{H}$, we can express it as a map $z\longmapsto \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$, where $ad-bc=1$

Comment: Aren't the elements of $\Gamma \setminus T_1 \mathbb{H}$ of the form $\{ (\gamma(p), v \gamma'(p) ) \ \big\vert \ \gamma \in \Gamma\}$ where $p \in \mathbb{H}, v \in \mathbb{C}$ and $v \gamma'(p) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\gamma(p+vh)-\gamma(p)}{h}$ ? And $T_1 (\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H})$ would be the same

Comment: @reuns: Yes, it has that form. But I don't think $T_1(\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H})$ would be the same, because it is not a quotient space.

Comment: Why not ? Using fundamental domains, it seems $T_1 (\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H})$ has the same points/topology/metric

Comment: You mean if $F$ is a fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{H}$, and $SF$ is a fundamental domain of $ \Gamma$ in $T_1\mathbb{H}$,  then $T_1F$ is the same to $SF$ ?

Comment: Yes but (in my understanding) the map $F \subset \mathbb{H} \to \Gamma( F) \subset \Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}$ is by definition an isomorphism (of Riemannian manifolds) so it is also an isomorphism of tangent spaces. All we need is to be careful with the different $F$ giving different charts, and the different $\gamma \in \Gamma$ are what we need to achieve this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I think if $F$ is a fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{H}$, then we can imply that $T_1F$ is a fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ in $T_1\mathbb{H}$. So we can say that they have the same fundamental domain, in other word, $\Gamma \backslash T_1 \mathbb{H}=T_1F/{\~}=T_1(\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H})$. But I think we need to explain more.

Comment: Take an open $U \subset \mathbb{H}$ sufficiently small such that $\varphi : U\to \Gamma(U)$, $\varphi(p) = \Gamma(p)$ is a local homeomorphism (a chart). It extends to a local homeomorphism of tangent bundles. This is how you can define $T_1 (\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H})$ and see it is the same as $\Gamma \setminus T_1\mathbb{H}$

Comment: I still don't understand why $T_1U \to \Gamma(T_1U)$ is a local homeomorphism :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll define the map and leave the proof that it is a diffeo to you. Assume $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $\Gamma$ is a torsion free group that acts properly discontinuously by isometries on $M$. Get the quotient map $M\to \Gamma\backslash M$.
Check that it is differentiable map between Riemannian manifolds which derivative at every point is an isometry and get an associated map $T^1M\to T^1(\Gamma\backslash M)$. Note that this map is $\Gamma$-invariant, thus factors through the orbit space $\Gamma\backslash (T^1M)$. Call the resulting map $\phi:\Gamma\backslash (T^1M)\to T^1(\Gamma\backslash M)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think we don't need the compactness of surface. We only need $\Gamma$ is torsion free and discrete, then $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$ will become a hyperbolic surface. Do you agree with that?

Comment: yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to think how do you define the structure of Riemannian manifold in $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb{H}$. For this you need an action in the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{H}$ which is same as the one you define to construct $\Gamma  \backslash T_1\mathbb{H}$, you can do this because  $\Gamma$ is an isometry. So the isomorphism is just the identity.

Comment: Could you write it clearer, please? Is it the same to use fundamental domain? How to use the compactness of surface?